# Graphing two vectors that are not the same size

Tags: matlab

How would I go about graphing two vectors that are not the same?

An error comes up saying that they cannot be displayed and so I realize that I probably need a primary y-axis and a secondary y-axis.

How would I go about this on MatLab?

Comment: probably `plot(1:numel(A),A,1:numel(B),B)` but your question isn't very clear.  What is in the vectors?  Dependent or independent variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plot multiple vectors of different lengths on the same plot using `hold on`.

Example:

```
vec1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
vec2 = [9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

figure;
plot(vec1);
hold on;
plot(vec2);
```

Example Output:

[image]